# Decryption of an encrypted password in node.js

Tags: node.js

How to decrypt the next snippet?

```
crypto.createHash('md5').update(password).digest('hex');
```

I tried to use http://lollyrock.com/articles/nodejs-encryption/ 
but it wont work.

Comment: You can't reverse hash functions (this is by design). They are 1-way injective functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code shows a very weak password hash approach. I recommend you look into bcrypt as your hashing algorithm instead.

However, the usual way to match passwords securely applies to most hash approaches (whether you use MD5 or another). You don't decrypt, instead you store the hashed password, and when a user enters a password, you verify it is correct by hashing the password they just entered and comparing with the value stored when they registered or set their password:

```
var existing_hashed_password = // fetched from storage
var login_attempt_hashed = crypto.createHash('md5').update(password).digest('hex');
if ( login_attempt_hashed === existing_hashed_password ) {
  // Successful login
} else {
  // Unsuccessful login
}
```

If you use a *salt* (which you should), then this becomes slightly more complex as you must apply the same salt to the new login attempt too. Most authentication libraries will have a function to do that for you.